# Uniformly continuous function with domain of subset of a compact metric space

Tags: general-topology

Let's say the function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ where $X$ is a subset of a compact metric space, and that $f$ is uniformly continuous as well.

Am I correct to say that the domain $X$ is compact as well?  Can someone prove it to me why, I'm just telling myself it's probably yes but I can't seem to able to prove if it's right or wrong so I don't want to assume I'm correct.

Ty for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are not correct. There are subsets of a compact metric space that are not compact. Example: $(0,1)\subset[0,1]$.

Comment: Ooops, I think I'm missing something ... I meant for functions that's uniformly continuous

Comment: Am I still wrong?

Comment: @user97994 A function that is uniformly continuous on $[0, 1]$ is also uniformly continuous on $(0, 1)$.

Comment: @user97994: just take the (any) constant function from $(0,1)$ to say $0 \in \mathbb{R}$.